# Frozen windows form application with checkbox c#

Tags: c#, if-statement, checkbox, freeze

Here is my situation, when I check the checkbox, my application freezes but still works. Which means that it is still able to recognize data sent through the serial port; for testing purposes it just exits the application.

If I comment out line 45 ("pipe = arduino.ReadLine();" see screenshot below) meaning that it no longer has to "ReadLine()", I am able to un-check the box. However now when I try to re-check the box, I get an error message saying ["Access to the port 'COM5' is denied"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcG5o.png)

I assume that the code cannot continue because it is trying to "ReadLine()" when nothing has been sent through yet. However I do not have an explanation for being denied access to the COM port; rather than me trying to open the port when its already opened.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SerialPort arduino = new SerialPort();
        arduino.BaudRate = 9600;
        arduino.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
        string pipe;

        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox1.Text = "Listening...";
            arduino.Open();
                pipe = arduino.ReadLine();
                if (pipe == "S\r")
                {
                    //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/f /r /t 0");
                    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
                }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Text = "Start";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SerialPort class manages system resources and, when such sensitive objects are involved, the class usually implements the IDisposable interface to allow those system resource to be released immediately to the system.

Your code forgets to close the SerialPort, so, the next time your user action cause a call to this event handler the port is in use by your own first action.

Fortunately, there is an easy way to ensure proper closing and disposing of such objects and it is the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        checkBox1.Text = "Listening...";
        using(SerialPort arduino = new SerialPort())
        {
           arduino.BaudRate = 9600;
           arduino.PortName = comboBox1.Text;
           string pipe;
           arduino.Open();
           pipe = arduino.ReadLine();
           if (pipe == "S\r")
           {

                //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("shutdown", "/f /r /t 0");
                //System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
           }
       } // Here the port will be closed and disposed.
    }
    else
    {
        checkBox1.Text = "Start";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution works, it no longer has denied access to the port, however it still freezes. I figured out why, the problem lies within the "ReadLine" statement, it gets stuck if there is nothing to read. Can you help me find a solution? I need a loop that repeats the "ReadLine" statement, however if nothing is found, then it needs to keep on looping rather than get stuck.

Comment: According to MSDN: _By default, the ReadLine method will block until a line is received. If this behavior is undesirable, set the ReadTimeout property to any non-zero value to force the ReadLine method to throw a TimeoutException if a line is not available on the port._ Of course at that point you catch the exception and start another loop.

Comment: When I loop `while (true){ arduino.ReadTimeout = 500; pipe = arduino.ReadLine();}` the program works, but I get a timeout error popup. Is there a way to use the 'ReadTimeout' without being interpreted as an error, but just refresh the 'ReadLine' statement? I don't think I used the loop in the right place.

Comment: I think you should post a new question with the details of your changed code and with the question focused on this problem. Do not forget to search if the site contains already an answer about SerialPort.ReadLine and timeouts.